# How do I setup a VPN connection on Ubuntu with a shared secret and group name if any?

Tags: ubuntu, vpn

I have the following VPN credentials that work perfectly from OS X:

```
Server Address: vpn.somewhere.com
Account Name: jbieber
Password: babybaby
Shared Secret: welovebieber
```

On Ubuntu 10.10, I can access the VPN settings from

```
System > Preferences > Network Connections > VPN
```

The above GUI has the following fields but I can't find any field for `Shared Secret`

```
Gateway:
User name:
Password:
NT Domain:
```

Has anyone successfully connected to VPN on Ubuntu with a `Shared Secret`?

**EDIT:**

I chose PPTP for the protocol.

Comment: You cannot set up a VPN without knowing exactly what protocol is being used (OpenVPN, PPTP, Cisco, L2TP, ...)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I use `vpnc`. Install it:

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-vpnc
```

Run it:

```
sudo vpnc
```

Enter connection data:

```
* IPSEC gateway: the hostname or IP of the VPN server
* IPSEC ID: the groupname
* IPSEC secret: the shared password for the group
* your username
* your password
```

You should also see a new option under `System > Preferences > Network Connections > VPN` to add a `Cisco Compatible VPN`

Answer (score 0):

**For Ubuntu users**

```
sudo apt install vpnc network-manager-vpnc network-manager-vpnc-gnome
```

- Go to `Settings > Network > VPN`
- Add VPN details
- Connect to VPN

This worked for me.